# Index View Index Creation Failing

Tags: sql-server-2005, view

I'm trying to create an index on a view and it keeps failing, I'm pretty sure its b/c I'm using an alias for the column.  Not sure how or if I can do it this way.  Below is a simplified scenario.

```
CREATE VIEW v_contracts WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT 
    t1.contractid as 'Contract.ContractID'
    t2.name as 'Customer.Name'
    FROM contract t1
    JOIN customer t2
    ON t1.contractid = t2.contractid
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX v_contracts_idx ON v_contracts(t1.contractid)
GO
---------------------------
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX v_contracts_idx ON v_contracts(contractid)
GO
---------------------------
Column name 'contractid' does not exist in the target table or view.

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX v_contracts_idx ON v_contracts(Contract.ContractID)
GO
---------------------------
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Anyone know how to create an indexed view using aliased columns please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using brackets around the column name because the name is not a valid column name

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX v_contracts_idx 
ON v_contracts([Contract.ContractID])
GO
```

Also indexed views require 5 or so SET options to be on, more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx

Comment: Yep that's its!  I can't believe I forgot about the [].  I use them all over the place.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about a **comma** between the two columns???

```
  SELECT 
     t1.contractid as 'Contract.ContractID'  -- <=== comma missing here
     t2.name as 'Customer.Name'
```

And I probably wouldn't really use "Contract.ContractID" as my alias..... the dotted notation has special meaning in SQL Server (database.schema.object) - so I would avoid anything that could cause trouble there.....

```
CREATE VIEW v_contracts WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT 
     t1.contractid as 'ContractID' ,   -- comma here at the end!!
     t2.name as 'CustomerName'
  FROM contract t1
    JOIN customer t2 ON t1.contractid = t2.contractid
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX v_contracts_idx ON v_contracts(ContractID)
GO
```

Comment: Yeah the comma was missing from my sample, but not the actual code.  Unfortunately i have to alias the column name with the dot notation b/c that is how our custom ORM maps fields to object properties and creates relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you aliasing the tables if you are simply going to re-alias the columns back to the original?? Just do

```
CREATE VIEW v_contracts WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT 
    Contract.ContractID,
    Customer.Name
    FROM contract
    JOIN customer
    ON contract.contractid = customer.contractid
GO
```

And yes, you were missing a comma.

Comment: trying to make it blatantly obvious that i was using two tables.